# Validar arquivo jpg - Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, validator

Estou tentando usar o `Validator` para validar o tipo do arquivo do upload mas não sei se a sintaxe está correta

```
    $data=Input::all();

    $file  = $data["picture_url"]; 
    $rules = array('picture_url' => 'required|max:10000|mimes:jpg');

    $validator = Validator::make($file, $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        echo "Arquivo inválido";
    }else{
        
    }
```

pois está dando o seguinte erro

> ErrorException in Factory.php line 91: Argument 1 passed to
> Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() must be of the type array,
> object given, called in
> C:\Users\user\Documents\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php
> on line 219 and defined

Alguém sabe como resolver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eis o problema. No Laravel, quando você pega um índice de um input referente a um arquivo de upload, ele retorna um objeto do `Symfony` chamado `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile\FilesBag` (quando possui mais de um arquivo de upload) ou então um `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile`.

Nesse caso, você deve passar o `array` contendo o seguinte par `['nome_do_indice_do_input' => 'valor_do_indice']`.

Então ao invés de fazer isso:

```
$data = Input::all();

 $file  = $data["picture_url"];
```

Faça assim:

```
  $file  = Input::only('picture_url')

  Validator::make($file, $rules);
```

Assim, ele pegará somente o índice `picture_url` e retornará um `array` contendo chave e valor do campo. Dessa forma, a validação deverá funcionar como esperado.

Você também pode opcionalmente manter seu código atual, alterando apenas a linha referente ao `Validator::make`, assim:

```
 Validator::make(['picture_url' => $file], $rules);
```

Comment: É, realmente funcionou! e alterei o rules para `$rules = array('picture_url' => 'required|image');`

Answer (score 1):

O $file passado como argumento no Validator tem que ser um array para comparar com o $rules, pois da forma que você está utilizando as variáveis você não está pegando o file.
você pode fazer da seguinte forma;

```
$data = Input::all();
$rules = array('picture_url' => 'required|max:10000|mimes:jpg');
$validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);
```

Comment: não acredito que o problema seja apenas pelo não uso do `Input::file` porque antes disse eu tinha feito um teste com o `Input::file` e somente `$data["picture_url"];` e eles retornaram o mesmo valor, objeto `Symfony` como nosso amigo ali em cima disse

Comment: Eu editei a resposta, você está certo

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha considere a respode do Miguel como complemento. Em alguns casos, a forma que ele fez pode ser mais simples. Por exemplo, se você estiver validando mais de uma coisa. O que não é validado pode estar também no array, não tem problema.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters sim...